# Perl confusion over grep {//} and eval {grep //} syntax

Tags: perl

Kindly shed some light on these two ways of **grep**'ping in **Perl** as how they differ from each other

```
eval {grep /pattern/, ....};
```

and the normal one,

```
grep {/pattern/} ....
```

Comment: The one with `eval` will ignore any exceptions thrown, but exceptions seem to be extremely unlikely when successively matching items in an array against a regexp. (Certainly possible, but unlikely.)

Answer (score 3):

First of all, there are 2 independent differences between your alternatives, and they have different purposes. Wrapping the `grep` in `eval` allows you to catch errors that are normally fatal (like a syntax error in the regular expression). Putting a block after the `grep` keyword lets you use a matching rule that is more complex than a single expression.

Here are the 4 combinations that can be made out of your 2 examples:

```
@y = grep /pattern/, @x;             # grep EXPR, no eval
@y = grep { /pattern/ } @x;          # grep BLOCK, no eval
eval { @y = grep /pattern/, @x };    # grep EXPR inside eval BLOCK
eval { @y = grep { /pattern/ } @x }; # grep BLOCK inside eval BLOCK
```

Now we can look in more detail at 2 separate questions: what do you gain from the `eval`, and what do you gain from using the `grep BLOCK` syntax? In the simple cases shown above, you gain nothing from either one.

When you want to do a `grep` where the matching condition is more complicated than a simple regexp, `grep BLOCK` gives you more flexibility in how you express the condition. You can put multiple statements in the block and use temporary variables. For example this grep within a grep:

```
# Note: not the most efficient method for finding an intersection of arrays.
my @a = qw/A E I O U/;
my @b = qw/A B D O P Q R/;
my @intersection = grep { my $x = $_; grep { $_ eq $x } @b } @a;
print "@intersection\n";
```

In the above example, we needed a temporary `$x` to hold the value being tested by the outer `grep` so it could be compared to `$_` in the inner `grep`. The inner `grep` could have been written without a BLOCK as `grep $_ eq $x, @b` but I think having using the same syntax for both looks better.

The `eval` block would be useful if you were looking for matches of a regexp that is determined at runtime, and you don't want your program to abort when the regexp is invalid. For example:

```
@x = qw/foo bar baz quux xyzzy/;
do {
  print STDERR 'Enter pattern: ';
  $pat = <STDIN>;
  chomp $pat;
  eval {
    @y = grep /$pat/, @x;
  };
} while($@);
print "result: @y\n";
```

We ask the user for a pattern and print the list of matches from `@x`. If the pattern is not a valid regexp, the `eval` catches the error and puts it into `$@`, and the program keeps running (The "Invalid" message is printed and the loop continues so the user can try again.) When a valid regexp is entered, there is no error so `$@` is false the "result" line is printed. Sample run:

```
Enter pattern: z$
result: baz
Enter pattern: ^(?!....)
result: foo bar baz
Enter pattern: ([^z])\1
result: foo quux
Enter pattern: [xyz
Invalid pattern
Enter pattern: [xyz]
result: baz quux xyzzy
Enter pattern: ^C
```

Note that `eval` doesn't catch syntax errors in a fixed regexp. Those are compiled when the script is compiled, so if you have a simple script like

```
perl -ne 'print if eval { /[xyz/ } or eval { /^ba/ }'
```

it fails immediately. The `eval`s don't help. Compare to

```
perl -ne '$x = "[xyz"; $y = "^ba"; print if eval { /$x/ } or eval { /$y/ }'
```

which is the same thing but with regexps built from variables - this one runs and prints matches for `/^ba/`. The first `eval` always returns false (and sets `$@` which doesn't matter if you don't look at it).